# Need help avoiding the use of a Singleton

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I'm not a hater of singletons, but I know they get abused and for that reason I want to learn to avoid using them when not needed.

I'm developing an application to be cross platform (Windows XP/Vista/7, Windows Mobile 6.x, Windows CE5, Windows CE6). As part of the process I am re-factoring out code into separate projects, to reduce code duplication, and hence a chance to fix the mistakes of the inital system.

One such part of the application that is being made separate is quite simple, its a profile manager. This project is responsible for storing Profiles. It has a `Profile` class that contains some configuration data that is used by all parts of the application. It has a `ProfileManager` class which contains `Profiles`. The `ProfileManager` will read/save `Profiles` as separate XML files on the harddrive, and allow the application to retrieve and set the "active" `Profile`. Simple.

On the first internal build, the GUI was the anti-pattern SmartGUI. It was a WinForms implementation without MVC/MVP done because we wanted it working sooner rather than being well engineered. This lead to `ProfileManager` being a singleton. This was so from anywhere in the application, the GUI could access the active `Profile`.

This meant I could just go `ProfileManager.Instance.ActiveProfile` to retrieve the configuration for different parts of the system as needed. Each GUI could also make changes to the profile, so each GUI had a save button, so they all had access to `ProfileManager.Instance.SaveActiveProfile()` method as well.

I see nothing wrong in using the singleton here, and because I see nothing wrong in it yet know singletons aren't ideal. **Is there a better way this should be handled?** Should an instance of ProfileManager be passed into every Controller/Presenter? When the ProfileManager is created, should other core components be made and register to events when profiles are changed. The example is quite simple, and probably a common feature in many systems so think this is a great place to learn how to avoid singletons.

P.s. I'm having to build the application against Compact Framework 3.5, which does limit alot of the normal .Net Framework classes which can be used.

Comment: I may just be stuck in my old habits, but I see this as a good example of where a Singleton should be used.

Comment: This actually sounds like the ideal case for a singleton instance.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, it appears this is a proper place to use a Singleton. Feedback on Factory/Dependency injection will be taken into account, however as this application will run in the background I will likely leave it as a Singleton for both simplicity and performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the reasons singletons are maligned is that they often act as a container for global, shared, and sometimes mutable, state. Singletons are a great abstraction when your application really does need access to global, shared state: your mobile app that needs to access the microphone or audio playback needs to coordinate this, as there's only one set of speakers, for instance.

In the case of your application, you have a single, "active" profile, that different parts of the application need to be able to modify. I think you need to decide whether or not the user's profile truly fits into this abstraction. Given that the manifestation of a profile is a single XML file on disk, I think it's fine to have as a singleton.

I do think you should either use dependency injection or a factory pattern to get a hold of a profile manager, though. You only need to write a unit test for a class that requires the use of a profile to understand the need for this; you want to be able to pass in a programatically created profile at runtime, otherwise your code will have a tightly coupled dependency to some XML file on disk somewhere.

Comment: The partial re-write will be unit tested, not a strong point of mine but I will try, still learning TDD. Not tested singletons yet, but i presume the issue is with them is that the Instance (method or property) is static so can't easily be mocked/stubbed as static can't be overridden which is how mocks work (adding in a test generated sub class of the class being mocked).

Answer (score 5):

One thing to consider is to have an interface for your ProfileManager, and pass an instance of that to the constructor of each view (or anything) that uses it. This way, you can easily have a singleton, or an instance per thread / user / etc, or have an implementation that goes to a database / web service / etc.

Another option would be to have all the things that use the ProfileManager call a factory instead of accessing it directly. Then that factory could return an instance, again it could be a singleton or not (go to database or file or web service, etc, etc) and most of your code doesn't need to know.

Doesn't answer your direct question, but it does make the impact of a change in the future close to zero.

Comment: I did consider an interface, but knew there was only ever going to be one type of ProfileManager so decided against it. Using Factory methods was another considered, but I hesitate to suggest it because I feel like I am adding in code that just returns a singleton anyway, but I do understand if implementations changes, then i only update the one factory reference, instead of every piece of code using that singleton. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

"Singletons" are really only bad if they're essentially used to replace "global" variables. In this case, and if that's what it's being used for, it's not necessarily Singleton anyway.

In the case you describe, it's fine, and in fact ideal so that your application can be sure that the Profile Manager is available to everyone that needs it, and that no other part of the application can instantiate an extra one that will conflict with the existing one. This reduces ugly extra parameters/fields everywhere too, where you're attempting to pass around the one instance, and then maintaining extra unnecessary references to it. As long as it's forced into one and only one instantiation, I see nothing wrong with it.

Singleton was designed to avoid multiple instantiations and single point of "entry". If that's what you want, then that's the way to go. Just make sure it's well documented.

Comment: Thanks for your input, my concerns with not having a "Singleton" and just a "Single Reference", is as you state, having extra parameters in lots of methods. Which eventually becomes a messy business.